# А что если [feature-request] != [предложение]?

Tags: обсуждение, метки, использование-метки

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) у нас переведён как [предложение](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5).

Пока я дополнял [вопрос](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/303062/309650) на metaSE, я понял, что в предложении

> Or how developers differentiate which proposals require development and which don't?

я вынужден использовать слово "proposal" вместо "feature request" потому что feature request — это именно то, что касается разработчиков. Например, вопросы о расширении тематики являются предложениями, но разве они действительно являются feature request'ами?

Comment: Как я считаю, proposal - это частный случай FR, то есть, он уже содержит в себе возможную реализацию. В общем виде FR может содержать только идею, без реализации.

Comment: А с чего бы это вдруг "feature request -- это то, что касается разработчиков"? Расширение тематики -- это тоже точно такой же фичериквест. Предлагаю договориться, что слова предложение и фичереквест являются синонимами как в русском, так и в английском (proposal = feature request) и не плодить излишние сущности без необходимости. Собственно, слово фиче риквест -- это плохая калька с английского, как раз слово "предложение" уместнее и звучит более привычно для русского уха. Нам разве реально есть нужда разделять ньюансы видов этих предложений/запросов/фичереквестов?

Comment: @AK 1. feature request = запрос (на добавление) функциональности. 2. А давайте разрешим вопросы по железу - это отношение людей, а не функциональность. 4. feature request - это частный случай proposal, а не наоборот. 5. Ответы - в ответы.

Comment: @alexolut, а я считаю наоборот, что feature-request - это частный случай poposal'а.

Comment: @Qwertiy есть четыре обязательные метки на Мете, которые покрывают все множество вопросов. В обсуждаемом случае FR вполне подходит.

Comment: @alexolut, вероятно, из обязательных меток для того, что, как я считаю, не подходит под [meta-tag:feature-request] вполне подойдёт [meta-tag:обсуждение]. Добавлять новую обязательную метку я НЕ предлагаю.

Comment: @Qwertiy никак не могу понять, а что поменялось в третьей ревизии вопроса? Вроде пробел остался пробелом.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, он стал неразрывным пробелом, при наборе кода которого я ошибся и вставил какую-то каракулю, которую ты поправил на обычный пробел :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Какую проблему мы пытаемся решить? Нам разве реально есть нужда разделять нюансы видов этих предложений/запросов/фичереквестов?

Я посмотрел на метамете: в метках нет отдельно "запроса функциональности" и "изменения функциональности":

> Proposals of **new** features on the Stack Exchange network, or requests
>   for a **change** to an existing feature.

[image: метки на метамете, содержащие слово request]

А если они не выделяют, то и нам вряд ли есть необходимость делать то же самое. Не надо плодить излишние сущности – гласит Бритва Оккама.

Предлагаю: договориться, что термины proposal и feature request идентичны и будут переводиться одним термином "предложение" (русские кальки с английского "фиче риквест" или "фиче реквест" могут быть использованы в качестве жаргонизма, не рекомендованного к официальному употреблению)

Comment: Проблема: англоговорящие разработчики должны как-то понимать, какие вопросы (на чужом языке) их касаются, а какие нет. И почему обязательно кальки, если есть нормальный перевод `запрос функциональности` или `изменение функциональности`?

Comment: Но перевод статей, синонимизация веток и тематика - это не предложение новых фич и не изменение существующих. Всё, что требуется, в движке сайта уже есть.

Comment: @Qwertiy предлагаете пятую метку "не лезь в наши локальные дела"?

Comment: @alexolut, нет, я НЕ предлагаю менять обязательные метки. Есть же [meta-tag:обсуждение].