# Запрос функциональности — это не [предложение]

Tags: дефект, локализация, мета, использование-метки

У нас метка [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) переведена как [предложение](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5), что в итоге порождает проблему в том, что метку лепят на любые "предложения", которые не требуют добавления никакой функциональности: давайте синоним добавим, давайте выборы проведём, давайте метку добавим и т.д. Также данное явление сильно противоречит [описанию данной метки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/info):

> Вопрос-предложение, описывающий идею новой или изменение существующей функциональности и поведения сайта. Для таких вопросов голоса «за» и «против» обозначают согласие или несогласие с предложением, а не качество или полезность вопроса.

В большинстве наших "предложений" должна быть метка [обсуждение](/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) и со временем надо будет по возможности изменять метки, но для начала, чтобы пресечь данное явление нужно переименовать метку. Кому хочется всё-таки оставить данную метку, то её всё-таки следует сделать отдельной, самостоятельной, никак не связанной с запросами функциональности.

---

В завершение подчеркну, что перевод (локализация), должна быть наиболее точной и соответвовать оригиналу. В англоязычной версии нет меток suggestion или proposal, поэтому я считаю, что нужно заменить этот вольный перевод на более точный.

Comment: [В прошлый раз](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6360/178988) решили по-другому...

Comment: @Qwertiy надо же, и я там есть :)

Answer (score 2):

Не надо ничего менять, (рас)синонимизировать и переименовывать. Зачем? Только лишь для тех, кто хочет разделить действительно запрос изменения/добавления функционала движка сайта от каких-то иных инициатив на конкретном сайте? Таких людей единицы, да и если нужно менять что-то в движке, постить надо на MSE и на английском, а не в нашей Мете, откуда эта идея просто не выберется наружу, если её не перевести на английский.

Метка [предложение](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) характерна для ситуаций, когда участник достаточно четко знает, что он хочет и собирается изменить. [обсуждение](/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) же для проблем требующих, как это ни странно, обсуждения, например, как поступить участнику с той или иной ситуацией, возникающей на сайте.

И, кстати, если глянуть в [синонимы](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/feature-request/synonyms) на Meta SO для feature-request, то там как раз можно увидеть [suggestion]. Так что всё нормально и так.

Comment: У них там куча уточняющих меток, производных от "request".

Comment: Очень странно от вас это слышать, мне казалось вы очень любите точность перевода, противоречие описанию вас тоже не смущает, что метка используется не по назначению?

Answer (score 0):

Сам грешу подобным, т.к. сбивает с толку само название метки. Если в английской для обычных "предложений" можно, к примеру, использовать **proposal** или **suggestion**, то что у нас?

В SOen для "предложений" просто есть расширенные метки вроде: [retag-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/retag-request), [tag-alias-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag-alias-request). Впрочем, [feature-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) в этом же списке, хотя, в целом, немного о другом. Так что, в SOen тоже есть эта проблема.

Может нам тоже стоит расширение метки [предложение](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) сделать? Или, как вариант(хотя уверен, многие не захотят), использовать английское наименование для таких меток?